# SQL Server 2008 - ssas user permission

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, permissions, ssas

I'm new to ssas and i'm fighting with users permissions...

I have a cube with a region dimension i.e region A and region B.

I created a role to filter dimension data so that members of that role have only access to region A.
I put user A in this role.

Now, when I test this configuration, if I select the role A in the security context, everything is fine: only region A is accessible.

But, if I choose user A in the security context, I have access to region A and region B, which is in my understanding, not the correct behavior.

So my question is : is it the correct behavior ? and if not, how can i solve it ?

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem once, but it turned out the user was actually a member of more than one role, so the security restrictions I thought he was inheriting were actually incorrect.  Is your current configuration limited to a single role and is that user a business user or non-privileged test account?